# Image not loading - "Failed to load the given URL"

Tags: html, css, image

I have an issue with firefox, it doesn't load an image.All the other,Chrome, Opera and IE can load this but firefox fails, it does not display any picture and if i go check with firebug it displays the following error on the image link: "Failed to load the given URL". I did clear my cache, also, if i open the image link in another tab it works.

THe code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li>
   <a style='padding:4px' href="<?php echo $login_url?>">
      <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>img/facebook_log22.png" class='facebookLogin' />
   </a>  
</li>
</ul>
```

Also in style:

```
.facebookLogin
{
height:40px;
}
```

I'm using codeigniter(if u wonder about base_url() function) and bootstrap(but i don't think that matters so much.

Edit: I also see that it adds another class to the code...
Also,the error:
[image]

Comment: Right click on the image area and select "Open image in new tab". If it loads then the URL is correct, if it doesn't load then the URL is incorrect and needs to be changed.

Comment: If you can edit the image, try re-exporting it in a different format such as `gif` or `jpeg` and then using that.

Comment: You can also check the network tab in your browser's dev tools to see if the image is loaded correctly

Comment: The URL works : http://sherlock-it.ro/img/facebook_log22.png

Comment: Yeah,i said that,the url works.Edited the picture so u won't see the link anymore,if u can,please remove the link:).

Tried to change the picture into jpg.Still got the same issue.

It's a firefox problem more likely than a web one.

Comment: @Mihai Stancu, i cannot right click the section.It's like a display:none,i cannot find it.

Comment: @harley , tried jpg,not working

Comment: @bchhun , it doesn't even try to load it

Comment: @RaduVlad I visited your site directly and debugged there. For me it works fine in `Chrome 28` as well as `Firefox 23`.

Comment: There is a `<li>` which has the ending `>` on a separate row (there's a `\n` in there somewhere). This might cause problems in some browsers but I doubt it.

Comment: Firefox 23.0.1 here,don't really know why this happens...Some others told me the same,I guess it's about my firefox,so i guess it may be closed.

Comment: Edited the <li>, no success

Comment: I'm on FFX Ubuntu let me try on my Windows 7 VM and I'll get back to you.

Comment: FFX 20 @ Win7 -- still works.

Comment: thanks..guess it's just my Firefox..

Comment: FFX 23.0.1 @ Win7 still works

Comment: Forgot to say....FFX 23.0.1 windows 8,but i'm sure it's about some ffx settings or something,not about the browser in general or the windows

thanks a lot,it can be closed, i guess

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Ok,i finally know what the problem was,and it is called adblock plus.Damnit,totally forgot i have that installed on my firefox.
Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: I would give you more points, I was going crazy ;_; <- tears of joy

Comment: THANK YOU! i was going crazy.

Comment: omfg same issue... the div was named "#ad_container1" so it was being blocked... smh

Comment: Thumbs up from me too! But changing the div name wasn't enough. I had to change the name of the jpg as well, so it won't include the word 'ad'

Comment: @Radu Vlad thanks a lot you saved me.. you are great

Answer (score 1):

If you are referencing image from domain, it will not work, unless you:

- put `http://` in front of your link: `src="http://<?php echo base_url(); ?>/img/facebook_log22.png"`, or
- create a relative link: `src="/img/facebook_log22.png"` .

Comment: Based on what Vucko put in as url, it is not.

Comment: Yeah it is. He just covered it up. If you look back on the original post you can see it has the `http://` in it.

Comment: My mistake then, but when I checked it in jsfiddle it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I also ha a similar error , i opened it again with a different browser it was working .
right click >View Image > you must be able to see your image if the link is correct .

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar problem and after a frustrating time of checking and rechecking my path, I realized the problem was the images were uploaded as ".JPG" but my css had ".jpg" It was a capitalization issue.

Comment: Kindly elaborate your Answer